# CSS :invalid works differently in Chrome v. FF?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to style my invalid  elements in my html forms; simple enough in Chrome, but Firefox refuses to listen to my :invalid pseudoclass.  Open the following in Chrome and Firefox to see what I mean:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            :invalid{
                color:#FF0000;
            };
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            This box validates on inputs between 0 and 100:
            <input class='myInput' type='number' min='0' max='100'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Put in 101 to the input box, and Chrome turns it red while Firefox ignores it.  Thoughts?

Comment: Start here ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Mounir.lamouri/HTML5_Forms) page

```
<input type='number'>
```

number : New input type : New input type for numbers : bug 344616 : In pause

---

From this [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/input-number) page :

Red =  Not supported

---

From this [more stable reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) (thanks to [jukka-k-korpela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084437/jukka-k-korpela)) :

type=number     6.0 (Localization in Chrome 11)     Not supported
Unimplemented (see bug 344616)

**It is not yet supported.**

a solution would be [using modernizr](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#modernizr)

Comment: A more stable reference: [MDN information about `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). So Firefox does not support this type, and it degrades to `input type=text`, with no constraints applied.

Comment: Oh wow it never occurred to me that 'number' wouldn't be implemented somewhere, sorry about that and thanks!

Comment: Well .. browsers tend to become Photoshop, so, don't worry